# Cannot add items to an IList/List being casted from an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, list, casting, ienumerable

I'm trying to create a small proof-of-concept application for my boss, however the code I've created that simulates what he's trying to pull off isn't working.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
{
     ((IList<string>) obj2.Stuff).Add("Iteration " + i.ToString());
}
```

I'm trying to pull this off all in one line because this is what his code looked like the other day in the framework we're working on. Anywho when the code above executes, I get a runtime error saying "Collection was of a fixed-size". And when I try casting to a List instead of an IList, I get an InvalidCastException saying "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'."

Anybody have any ideas on how I can pull off a single-line cast to add an item to the IEnumerable or help me figure out a way around the two errors I keep getting? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** (4/19/2011 10:49AM EST)
I'm adding more code to help people out -- probably should've done this earlier. Sorry.

Program.cs:

```
        #region Cast Test
        Class1 obj2 = new Class1();
        obj2.Stuff = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

        Console.WriteLine("Cast - Start Time: " + 0 + "ms");

        Stopwatch stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            ((IList<string>) obj2.Stuff).Add("Iteration " + i.ToString());
        }

        stopwatch2.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Cast - Stop Time: " + stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + "ms");
        #endregion
```

Class1.cs:

```
public class Class1
{
    private IEnumerable<string> stuff;

    public IEnumerable<string> Stuff
    {
        get { return stuff; }
        set { stuff = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the REAL type of obj2.Stuff? from the exception it looks like a string[] ?

Comment: Please post the code where `obj2.Stuff` is defined.  My hunch is that `obj2.Stuff` is an array instead of a List type.

Comment: @Daniel & Muad'Dib: obj2 is just an object. Stuff is just an IEnumerable<string> property of said-object.

Comment: `IEnumerable<string>` has no `Add` method. Casting it to a different type does not magically create new properties, it just exposes them if they already exist.

Comment: Are you boxing to `IEumerable`?

Comment: @Daniel: Trying to unbox on the fly (pending I'm not getting my terminology mixed-up). I'm about to post more code to help people out.
@jamietre: I know -- hence why I'm trying to cast it to an IList or List which does have an Add method.

Comment: But you can't do that. If it "is" an `IEnumerable` and nothing else, then there is no concept of casting it to something it doesn't implement. If the underlying type of `obj2.Stuff` does not natively implement `IList` then you can't cast it to `IList`. As you have discovered it will compile, since type casting is resolved at run time, but it won't work.

Comment: @jamietre: Can I mark a comment as an accepted answer? lol. Your last comment is pretty-much what I was looking for (if there's no solution meeting my criteria, letting me know what I'm asking for isn't doable). If you want points, post that comment in an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments on one of the answers above you say "I'm trying to avoid copying the list."

You are trying to add data to an object whose underlying type is `IEnumerable<T>`. But an `IEnumerable` object is not an actual container, it's an interface. You can't add stuff to an interface. But you can assign another object that implements that interface to it.

So to use foson's example above, you could just do:

```
obj2.Stuff = Enumerable.Range(0, 5000).Select(i => "Iteration " + i.ToString());
```

Note that when this code executes, *nothing actually happens*. No objects will be created until something actually iterates over `obj2.Stuff`. When that happens, the methods in LINQ will be called that create objects one at a time and return them to the iterator loop.

But there's no actual storage device involved here. You can iterate over `obj2.Stuff` and unless you consequently added each integer to something else, they would be gone at the next iteration.

The fundamental point here is you can't store things in `IEnumerable`, rather, `IEnumerable` is a way to return objects in sequence, and that could be from a list construct, or from a function that generates a sequence.

Comment: Actually that line of code does create one object.  An object that implements 'IEnumerable<string>'.  What you really mean is that none of the objects in the enumeration are created.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, objects in the enumeration.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in C# are of fixed size. You can't add items to them.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast a `string[]` to `IList<string>` because `string[]` does not implement that interface. You will need to create an object implementing `IList<string>` first:

```
List<string> list = obj2.Stuff.ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
{
     list.Add("Iteration " + i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: We're trying to avoid copying the IEnumerable into a List (because in the framework we'd then have to assign the list back to the IEnumerable; we're trying to figure out which would be more efficient: copying or converting). Thank you (and +1) for the technical explanation though regarding my IList<string>/string[] error -- I'd been dealing with crap VBScript the past six months before I started my new job here so I'm a tad rusty on C#.

Comment: Actually you can cast `string[]` to `IList<string>`, but `IsFixedSize` will be true which will cause an exception when you call `Add`.

Comment: @juharr: Yup -- definitely ran into that issue. :(

Answer (score 1):

Why cast inside the for loop?   While every IList is an IEnumerable, not every IEnumerable is an IList.   You can use the ToList extention method to copy the IEnumerable to a new List.  (Just be sure to be `using System.Linq;`)

Also, in this example, there is no need for a for loop:

```
var list = obj2.Stuff.ToList();
new list.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 5000).Select(i => "Iteration " + i.ToString()));
```

Comment: +1 for the one-line replacement of a loop (and it provided me w/a useful example of Lambdas [which I don't fully understand]). Unfortunately I can't use this solution because I'm specifically trying to avoid copying my object into a list.

Answer (score 0):

An `IEnumerable` does not give you the same features that an `IList`. Unless your `Stuff` is an `IEnumerable` that is also an `IList` your code won't work.

The contract of the first only promises that you can iterate it one element at a time. It never states that you can add new elements.

You can only pull this off if and only if at runtime your enumerable object also satisfies the `IList` interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `Add` since `obj2.Stuff` seems to be an array, and an array has a fixed size, as the error message indicates.

Answer (score 0):

The  type `System.String[]` is an array of strings, which implements `IEnumerable<string>` but *is not* a `List<string>`. Arrays are of fixed length. Why do you need it in one line?

Comment: I suppose it could be two or more so long as I'm able to pull off my cast successfully (not make a copy of the object).

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of obj2.Stuff to something like StringCollection or List . In .NET arrays are of fixed length and you can't add new objects to them, so use collections instead.

Answer (score 0):

As `obj2.Stuff` is a string array, it's not possible to do what you are trying to do. An array can't be resized, so you can't add items to it.

If you can replace the array in `obj2.Stuff` with another array, you can get the data from the array and make a list from it, add items to the list, get the data from the list and create an array from it, and use that to replace the original array:

```
List<string> items = new List<string>(obj2.Stuff);
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
  items.Add("Iteration " + i.ToString());
}
obj2.Stuff = items.ToArray();
```

If the `obj2.Stuff` property is read-only, then you can't add anything to it unless you change then underlying implementation from an array to a collection that you can add items to.

Comment: obj2.Stuff is an IEnumerable. True that can't be resized but you can cast it to IList (or something else with an Add() method) which will allow you to resize it.

Comment: @KSwift87: Yes, it's an `IEnumerable<string>`, but your error message shows that it's actual type is `string[]`. Although you can cast it to `IList<string>`, it's still an array, and can't be resized. As arrays implement the `IList<T>` interface, they have an `Add` method, but you can't use it to add items to the array as all it does is to throw a `NotSupportedException`.