# Better solution to copy IEnumerable<T> to IList<T> using reflection

Tags: c#, collections, system.reflection

### I have provided a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/moqCNW) to show the issue.

I try to copy object from a source that have the same property names and type except some  properties that have IEnumerable  and target object has
IList using reflection.

```
public T CopyTo<T>(object src)
        where T : new()
    {
        var targetObj = new T();
        //Getting Type of Src
        var sourceType = src.GetType();
        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty;
        var sourcePi = sourceType.GetProperties(flags);
        foreach (var property in sourcePi)
        {
            var pi = targetObj.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name);
            if (pi == null || !pi.CanWrite)
                continue;
            object sourceValue = property.GetValue(src, null);
            //var sourceValue = Convert.ChangeType(property.GetValue(src, null), pi.PropertyType);  
            //this works, but hard wired
            if (sourceValue is IEnumerable<string> i)
                sourceValue = ((IEnumerable<string>)i).Cast<string>().ToList();
            pi.SetValue(targetObj, sourceValue, null);
        }

        return targetObj;
    }
```

It raises an error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Object of type 'System.String[]' cannot be
> converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.'

I tried to convert:

```
    var sourceValue = Convert.ChangeType(property.GetValue(src, null), pi.PropertyType);
```

but also get error
`System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.`

this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718077/cannot-add-items-to-an-ilist-list-being-casted-from-an-ienumerable) can't help.

My workaround solution is casting :

```
    sourceValue = ((IEnumerable<string>) sourceValue).Cast<string>().ToList();
```

The disadvantage is hard wiring the cast to `IEnumerable<string>`

Is there a better way to copy  `IEnumerable<T> to IList<T>`  or any generic collection using reflection.

Comment: Can you not change the `List<string>` on your model to `IList<string>`? Arrays implement IList already.

Comment: This sounds like an "XY problem." Using reflection to set properties is the _approach_ you've chosen, but it's not the problem you're actually trying to solve. If you share more about your use case, we might be able to offer better solutions, like serializing `A` to JSON and deserializing it to `B`. What are you trying to accomplish, and what are the constraints you're working under?

Comment: Why not just `i.ToList()`? And what's the problem with casting to `IEnumerable<string>` if you know that is already of that type via the `is` statement?

Comment: To answer the question, no there's no safe generic way to convert an `IEnumerable` to an `IList`. `ToList` is probably the easiest way.

Comment: @DStanley, There is other generic properties of ` IENumerable<int>` and I want to avoid multi switch cases for type conversion.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, I want to avoid Serialize and Deserialize to avoid add extra package to the project. The source is class with over 40+ property and it's copied to other different classes.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, I used `IList` and can help in solving the problem. I want to find the side effect of change because it's public API and the class is used by other clients.

Comment: I see so you have `IEnumerable<string>` and other types and want to generically convert to IList<{thattype}>`?

Comment: It is still not clear why you can't just call generic `Enumerable.ToList<T>` as you seem to have the same inner type of source and target (also as @DStanley pointed out base on your comments inner type are actually different - some edit, ideally with inline sample, would be nice)

Comment: @DStanley, yes that is true. I think  a generic converter from `IEnumerable<T> to IList<T>` can help without many switch cases.

Comment: Well, `ToList` _does_ that; the problem is that you want to do it at _runtime_ based on the property type, which generics is not great at. You _could_ call `Enumerable.ToList<T>` at runtime using reflection, but i gets ugly. Or you could try using `dynamic` to do the generic binding at runtime. Libraries such as `AutoMapper` can do most of the grunt work for you.

Comment: @DStanley, I know AutoMapper, I may use in case no solution :).

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to check if `IEnumerable<T>` is assignable from the source property's type, check if the destination property's type is assignable from `List<T>`, and if so then assign a new `List<T>` to the destination property passing the source property's value into the constructor.

```
public T CopyTo<T>(object src) where T : new()
{
    var targetObj = new T();
    var sourceType = src.GetType();
    BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty;
    var sourcePi = sourceType.GetProperties(flags);
    foreach (var property in sourcePi)
    {
        var pi = targetObj.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name);
        if (pi == null || !pi.CanWrite)
            continue;
        object sourceValue = property.GetValue(src, null);
        //var sourceValue = Convert.ChangeType(property.GetValue(src, null), pi.PropertyType);  
        //this works, but hard wired
        if (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
        {
            Type enumerable = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(property.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments);
            if (enumerable.IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
            {
                Type list = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(property.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments);
                if (pi.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(list))
                {
                    var pValue = Activator.CreateInstance(list, new[] { sourceValue });
                    pi.SetValue(targetObj, pValue, null);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            pi.SetValue(targetObj, sourceValue, null);
        }
    }

    return targetObj;
}
```

It isn't hard to imagine situations where this wouldn't work... for example if the destination type's property is `LinkedList<T>` or `T[]` then the properties won't copy. You'd have to modify it further to handle cases like this.

This would also create a new `List<T>` for the destination object even if the properties on the two objects are both exactly the same type. It isn't clear if that is what you want or not, but it is different from how other properties are copied by this method so it is worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried your code, adding a new property to the class A,B then run, get Exception
`Unhandled exception. System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found.`, see [source](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GFXSxJ)

Comment: I resolved the issue, by checking for null and skipping null values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a check of the destination type too.

And then, With the two different type (source and destination),
You can create a function that will handle the conversion/cast.

Something like this:

```
1. Source IEnumerable<T>, Destination: List<T> => Create New list and put in CTOR

2. Source List<T>, Destination: List<T> => Just Copy

3. Source List<T>, Destination: IEnumerable<T> => Create a list

4. Source IEnumerable<T> ,Destination: IEnumerable<T> => Made a copy?
```